# Label Staging Site to Prevent it from Being Used as if it Were the Production Site

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, testing, deployment, .net-2.0

Sorry for the insanely long title, I find this one hard to sum up. I'm being asked to maintain several internal-only web apps for my company. For testing, after making my changes, I've created some staging sites which make use of separate databases. As such, if my users were to mistakenly use this site as if it were the production site, they may enter important data and wonder where it "disappeared" to thinking it was the production server.

I'd like to create a big banner of some sort across the top of the staging site (which ONLY appears on the staging site) to remind my users that they are on the test site. I'd like recommendations on the best way to do this, with the following considerations:

```
IDE: Visual Studio 2008
Server: Windows 2003 with IIS 6
Language: VB.NET 2.0
```

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a web.config app setting that contains a specific value in staging.  Then in your master page(s) code behind(s) - assuming you're using them - write some code in that inserts an appropriately styled HtmlGenericControl (as a div) into a PlaceHolder control in the master page markup.  All this occurs based on whether the app setting has the value indicating the staging environment.

Comment: Indeed, but is there a way to ensure that the configuration is automatically switched based on where it's running from, or deployed to? Any other trigger? I hate to rely on my own memory to toggle it back and forth every time. >.<

Comment: How are you changing the database accessed by staging?  Are you relying on your memory for that?  Would use of a registry setting instead of an app setting work better for you?

Comment: No no, hehe. There's a Production DB for the Production server and a Dev DB for the Staging server.

Comment: How do you manage changing the database connection strings?  Could the same process be leveraged to include changing an app setting?  Another thought - depending on your setup you could also examine the domain and/or port in the request to indicate your environment.

Comment: Exactly Mark. The most normal thing to do when deploying to multiple environments is fiddle with things in the web.config. If you're not doing that now because the DBs are on localhost, it's time to work it into your deploy process. It'll come up again. Have a script that does the deployment and update config as part of that script. MSBuild as a FileUpdate task that can do the job of messing with WebConfig. Or, if you don't trust dev changes to those files, you could keep different copies of the file on each server (off to the side). Overwrite the normal one w/ the server one at deploy time.

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I'd make the staging site have a different color background.

White background -- public and live.
Pink background -- staging, liable to be reformatted any second.

Comment: Indeed, but I'm looking for the automation piece (i.e. how to do it in code) rather than the styling, lol, but yeah I agree, hehe.